# How to make calculations of column 1 and 2 in column 3 in data grid view windows form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want the subtraction of `column 1` and `column 2` in `column 3` for a data grid view in windows form using C#. As of my knowledge we need to give cell content click event

```
//how to specify click only for column3
private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  //here i need to give like column3 = column2 - column1 

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [click event for a individual cells in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496707/click-event-for-a-individual-cells-in-gridview)

Comment: Do you want the value to be permanently calculated, or should it be only calculated on a click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give here a code example demonstrating the use of a calculated column in a DataTable.  This may be sufficient for your purposes.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable dt;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col1", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col2", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col3", typeof(int), "col2 - col1"));
        var newRow = dt.NewRow();
        newRow[0] = 5;
        newRow[1] = 7;
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        newRow = dt.NewRow();
        newRow[0] = 12;
        newRow[1] = 19;
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Rows[0][0] = 10;
    }
}
```

The button click is deliberately crude, but I hope it is sufficient to demonstrate that if one field in the calculation alters, the calculation is refreshed immediately.